# Use XCode to develop console client/server application

Tags: xcode, client-server, console-application, xcode4.5

I have a console-based server and client application which talk to each other over a TCP socket on localhost (although eventually will be used on separate machines).

I see that if I manually launch the server target and then the client, XCode seems happy enough to run them both in separate debugger contexts, they connect and work just fine.

Ideally I'd like to set it up (via a scheme or pre-run step or something) such that I can one-click 'run' (or cmd-R) and both these contexts pop up and run happily.

So far my experiments with the post-run script (for the server) passing "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/cclient" to /bin/sh seems not to work, and this is less than ideal anyway because it wouldn't run in a debugger context anyway.

Is there a way i can easily set this up?

Thanks,
DaveM

EDIT: Added a screenshot of what I can achieve with several clicks, but would like to get to with one click/key-combo...

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up scripts and other actions in breakpoints.

Click on the left side of editor to create a breakpoint, and CMD+OPT+click on the breakpoint icon to edit its options.

Also, you can choose the 'Automatically continue after evaluation' option, for convenience.

For details, see Session 412 Debugging in Xcode from [WWDC 2012 videos](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/). This session just happened to demo debugging skills with Xcode in a client-server setting.

Comment: Thanks - this looks promising. Unfortunately I am too novice at applescript to get a useful script. I'm experimenting in the AS editor, and trying to make sense of XCode's dictionary but haven't yet gotten a script which is able to start a debug session for a named build target in the project.

Comment: You can use any scripting languages like sh, perl, python and apple script etc.

Comment: Thanks again, I can see how this could be used to spawn an instance of the client, say when the server is ready to accept connections. In this case the newly spawned process seems unknown to XCode so the debugger is unaware of it.

However I am still holding out in the hope of my ideal solution where both are running as two debug sessions in the XCode UI, just as if I run one target, switch to the other and then ran that to. Can switch he console pane between output from either, see either's frames, etc.

Comment: Unless you mean use the scripts to automate XCode to start a 2nd debug session, in which case it's not clear to me how I'd achieve that. 

Having one target being debugged and one off in the background is better than all this manual clicking, but still not ideal.
I've updated the Q with a screenshot of how this 'holygrail' looks when I do it manally